# Expressjs & Angular for SameCookie Chrome 80

Tags: angular, express, session-cookies, samesite

Hello I am using Angular for client-side & ExpressJS on server-side.
Since Chrome 80 my Web App is not working on Chrome, all fine on other browser.

All that is on Azure cloud.

I tried to set cookie on express :

```
app.use(cookieParser())
app.use(session({
  secret: 'aSecretKey',
  resave: false,
  saveUninitialized: true,
  store: new MemoryStore({
    checkPeriod: 86400000 // prune expired entries every 24h
  }),
  cookie: { 
    maxAge: 86400000,
    secure: true,
    sameSite: 'none'
  },
}));
```

And set the cookie response header manually :

```
if(req.cookies["connect.sid"]){
    res.setHeader('Set-Cookie', [
      `connect.sid=${req.cookies["connect.sid"]}; SameSite=None; Secure`,
    ]);
}else if(req.sessionID){
    res.setHeader('Set-Cookie', [
      `connect.sid=${req.sessionID}; SameSite=None; Secure`,
    ]);
}
```

This do not working, it generate a new sessionId on each request.

Thanks for help.

[Request & Response headers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2m2qp.png)

[Request & Response cookies](https://i.stack.imgur.com/un4Wp.png)